# Deforming metrics from non-negative to positive Ricci curvature

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ricci-curvature

Given a closed Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ with non-negative Ricci curvature and $dim\geq 3$, when can we deform the metric to a positive Ricci curved one?

I know it's impossible in general due to the flat factor in the universal covering. But what about we add some topological restrictions on $M$ like simply connectedness? Are there any positive or negative results on this problem?

( Besides, are there now any examples of simply connected closed manifold with positive scalar curved metric by do not admit a positive Ricci curved metric? )

------------------------------------------------------------update 1------------------------------------------------------------

Thanks to the answer by Robert, I may simplify the problem in the following sense,

Given a simply connected flat Einstein manifold $(M,g)$ with $\hat{A}$-genus non-vanishing, and set $(\mathbb{S}^2,h)$ be the standard unit sphere, can $(M\times \mathbb{S}^2, g+h)$ be perturbed to a Ricci-positive manifold? $\ \ $In general, what about changing $(\mathbb{S}^2,h)$ to an arbitrary closed Ricci-positive manifold?

Comment: It is better to ask the follow up question separately.

Comment: On the bottom of p.3 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.00657.pdf D.Wraith discusses a related question. He considers the product of a K3 surface with a homotopy $(4n-1)$-sphere $\Sigma$ that bounds a parallelizable manifold. (Wraith proved elsewhere that any such sphere admits a metric of $Ric>0$ so $K3\times\Sigma$ has a metric of $Ric\ge 0$). Wraith then remarks: "There are no known obstructions to positive Ricci curvature for these manifolds... Nevertheless, the author is tempted to conjecture that no Ricci positive metrics exist".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are obstructions.  Perhaps the most famous comes from the theorem that, if a compact spin manifold has a metric of positive scalar curvature, then its $\hat A$-genus must vanish.

If you take a compact Riemannian spin manifold $(M,g)$ with special holonomy $\mathrm{G}_2$ (in dimension $7$), $\mathrm{Spin}(7)$ (in dimension $8$), or holonomy in $\mathrm{SU}(n)$ (in dimension $2n$) whose $\hat A$-genus is nonzero (and there are lots of these, even simply-connected ones), then $g$ will be Ricci-flat and hence will have non-negative Ricci curvature.  However, by the above theorem, it cannot carry any metric with positive scalar curvature, let alone a metric with positive Ricci curvature.

Comment: This is why I asked the second question. So what about supposing Ricci non-negative and scalar positive on the metric, can it be deformed to a Ricci positive one? In general, what Riemannian manifold could be on the boundary of the space of non-collapsing positive Ricci curved manifolds?

Answer (score 9):

This is not a complete answer but would be helpful. Here are a few facts:

**Theorem ([T. Aubin 1970](http://dx.doi.org/10.4310/jdg/1214429638) and [P. Ehrlich 1976](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF00145952)).** If the Ricci curvature of a compact Riemannian manifold is
non-negative and positive somewhere, then the manifold carries a metric with
positive Ricci curvature.

Also vanishing the first Betti number is a necessary condition in compact case for admitting strictly
positive Ricci curvature.

**Relation with scalar curvature:**

1. There are still *no known* examples of simply connected manifolds that admit
   positive scalar curvature but not positive Ricci curvature
2. If a manifold $M$ cannot have a metric with positive (or zero) Scalar curvature, then it certainly does not admit a metric with positive (zero res.) Ricci curvature.

This paper of G. Perelman is also useful: "Construction of manifolds of positive Ricci curvature with big volume and large Betti numbers". Comparison Geometry. 30: 157–163 [Click here for pdf](http://www.msri.org/publications/books/Book30/files/perricci.pdf)